# Java DatagramSocket(UDP Socket) only receives when previously have sent a packet

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp, voip

I have the following problem:

I have an extremely simple Java Datagram client and server located on a remote machine. And the client will not receive anything from the server unless it sent a packet to the server earlier(it doesn't matter what information did the packet hold)

Here is what my client looks like:

```
    public static void TheClient() throws Exception { 
        ds = new DatagramSocket(clientPort); 
        while(true) { 
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);   
            ds.receive(p); 
            System.out.println(new String(p.getData(), 0, p.getLength())); 
        } 
    }
```

Basically all it does is listen on port clientPort and then prints whatever it receives. However it does not work.

Now slightly modifying it solves the problem:

```
public static void TheClient() throws Exception {
    ds = new DatagramSocket(clientPort); 

    //Sending an empty packet
    byte tempBuffer1[] = new byte[10];
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(
            tempBuffer1, tempBuffer1.length, address, serverPort);
    ds.send(packet1);

    while(true) { 
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 
                buffer.length);     
        ds.receive(p); 
        System.out.println(new String(p.getData(), 0, 
                p.getLength())); 
    } 
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem? While the workaround did solve the problem it doesn't make any sense to me why it wouldn't work originally so the solution might not actually work on all the computers.

Also, it should be noted that the code works fine when both the client and the server are on the same machine.

Comment: Have you determined that there isn't a firewall on the problematic client node?  Some firewalls will open up UDP return traffic automatically, but only if initiated by the client first.

Comment: I just added a rule to my firewall to allow all the connections to that UDP port and that hasn't solved the problem. Besides, other application using UDP such as Skype worked fine on my machine without the need to tweak any firewall settings. I would prefer to do as much as possible on the programming side.

Comment: Are you certain the server is sending you the packets?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% certain of that, since everything works fine when I just add those 4 lines to the client. And everything works fine on localhost(even without those 4 lines). I could post the server code as well, but I think that would be redundant.

Comment: Did you just add a rule to your local machine's firewall or is there also a gateway (router etc.) you could add a rule to (or port-forwarding)?

Comment: @Seismoid Yes, apparently that was the issue. I responded to phatfingers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if your PC is using a private IP address, typically one starting with either "10.x.x.x" or "192.168.x.x".  If so, the most likely cause is that you're using a NAT-based firewall which shares a single public address and multiple private addresses.

When you send a packet outbound, the firewall knows which internal address should receive the return packet.  When a connection is initiated from an external address, however, it has no way of knowing what internal address should receive the traffic.  Most SOHO (small office / home office) routers will allow you to "port forward" traffic to a specific internal IP address.  If you're using DHCP, you'll want to assign yourself a static IP address or your port forwarding may stop working at some future date because it grabs a different IP address.

Comment: But to do port-forwarding I would need to go into my router's settings and obviously I can't ask all the users of my application to do that. Would you know of a way to do that from the Java code? For example skype which I mentioned earlier doesn't ask users to turn on any port-forwarding, and yet it works fine.

Comment: How will your "server" know the "client's" IP address if the communication is not initiated by the client, and the client seems to be allowed to be behind a NAT router with, quite likely, a dynamic IP address?? It sounds reasonable that the communication should be initiated by the client, therefore eliminating your original problem.

Comment: In the example I provided I hardcode the client's IP, however, in my actual application I send the IP using a TCP socket. Besides, DatagramSockets are supposed to work without initiating a connection, according to their description in Java docs.

Comment: One way applications like Skype work around NAT servers is by brokering connections between clients using a public server.  Client A wants to talk/chat/video/game with Client B but their firewalls prevent them from initiating a conversation.  Server C, on a public address, can be addressed by both.  Each client opens a connection to the server and holds it open.  It can then either relay packets between both clients or use a protocol like STUN to perform a handoff, allowing the clients to communicate directly.

Comment: @phatfingers I was sort of assuming that Skype(or any other video/voice streaming software for that matter) uses UDP to send and receive the data. But yes, after reading into it a bit more it seems like receiving data by a client is usually done through TCP or other protocols(unless there is no firewall). In either case, your original response has saved me tons of time and I fixed the issue I had with my application by switching to using UDP only to send data to server and TCP to receive data. Thank you a lot! You have no idea how helpful that was.

Comment: Glad I could help.  But to be clear, TCP and UDP both are impacted in the same way.  The NAT router presents only one IP address to the world and may serve many on its private network.  Whether TCP or UDP, something has to tell the router which of the many internal addresses should receive the one inbound packet.  It boils down to one of two options: Either the internal client sends out a packet (TCP or UDP) with a return port that the router uses to temporarily route matching inbound traffic, or the router is permanently configured to route to a specified address based on that port.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on `AWS EC2`. The port on the client side is not opened on your firewall (security group). When your client sends a packet to the server, the firewall allows the data from the server for a short of time. The client can receive from the server without sending anything to the server if the client port on the firewall is opened.